# HP Loadrunner cannot reserve memory

Tags: java, jvm, loadrunner

I have the following problem - when I try to run any vuser of any script the LR gives me the following error:

```
Notify: VM Params: -Xms256m
Notify: Error occurred during initialization of VM
            [MsgId: MMSG-22986]
Notify: Could not reserve enough space for object heap               [MsgId: MMSG-22986]
Notify: 
            [MsgId: MMSG-22986]
```

I didn't find anything about "MsgId: MMSG-22986" message, at least not helpful in my case. I tried adding "-Xmx256m" and result was the same.

Also, as I read through other related topics, I ran another program with -Xms256m and everything was perfectly fine (so I made a conclusion that the problem is not insufficient memory). The machine is running 32-bit Win Server 2003 SP1 and Java 1.6.0_45. I tried re-installing Java and Loadrunner but that didn't help also.

I welcome any ideas.

EDIT: I'm sure that the problem occurs when LR tries to reserve memory while initializing a VM, but I have no idea why it fails, and only LR has that problem.

EDIT 2: We are running Java users. Issue occurred after adding system var "_JAVA_OPTIONS" with value "-Xmx512m", but the problem persists even after the var is removed.

Comment: Please clarify the user types (web, C template, DCOM, Winsock, VB, JAva template, ...) and when this specific issue began

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key in solving the issue was the version of Loadrunner. It turned out that Loadrunner 11.52 demands to have 3GB user addressable memory (i.e. you must have the [/3GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) parameter set in the boot.ini file of the OS) which is not the case with LR 11.04(it works with only 2GB addressable memory) and so the aforementioned system variable has nothing to do with the problem.

Cheers.